# Spring Interface Projection with UUID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, projection

I'm trying to use a [JPA Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) (Spring v1.5.9.RELEASE) to return a custom type from a `JpaRepository` as follows (MCVE):

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Void, Void> {

    public interface TestValue {
        UUID getId();
        int getNum();
    }

    @Query(value = "SELECT :id as id, 1 as num", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TestValue> getTestValues(@Param("id") UUID id);
    
}
```

I would like to use the repository as follows:

```
List<TestValue> testValues = testRepository.getTestValues(UUID.randomUUID());
int num = testValues.get(0).getNum(); // Returns 1 as expected
UUID id = testValues.get(0).getId(); // ***Fails with an exception***
```

However, calling `getId()` fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory.createProjection(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:110) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory.createProjection(SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory.java:42) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.getProjection(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:264) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.getId(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at ***my.company***
```

The returned `TestValue` proxy object stores the `id` attribute as a raw `byte` array. I would expect that the `ProjectingMethodInterceptor` eventually performs the actual type conversion to a `UUID` instance. Looking at the source code (`ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(..):74`) it seems that it uses a `ConversionService` to do conversions. I tried the following:

```
@Configuration  
public class MyApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        DefaultConversionService service = new DefaultConversionService();
        service.addConverter(new UUIDConverter());
        return service;
    }
}
```

The class `UUIDConverter` implements the interface `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<byte[], UUID>`. Unfortunately, **this approach does not work** as the used `ProjectingMethodInterceptor` is created via the `ProxyProjectingFactory` which bypasses the configured `ConversionService` and instantiates a `DefaultConversionService` (`ProxyProjectionFactory.ctor():65`).

I also tried to add the annotation `@Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)` to the `getId()` declaration in `TestValue`, however, **this approach does not work either**.

I obviously could change the return type of the `getId()` method to `byte[]` and perform the actual conversion to `UUID` in my application code, but this approach does not feel to be the right way to do it.

> Question 1:
> How are custom type conversions defined in *JPA Interface Projections*?
>
> Question 2:
> If this is not possible, what is the "Spring-intended" way to implement the above repository method with that exact method signature and underlying query.

Comment: I found a working solution here (in the question itself, not in the accepted answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417190/spring-data-jpa-custom-type-conversion-in-interface-based-projection

Comment: you can also remove `@Param("id")` as long as the parameter name is identical in the query string