# Convert a string to an enum description in a JPA projection interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a projection interface used in a native query in Spring JPA, one of the values ​​mapped as String is an enum inside Java.

I would like to get the enum description field based on the string returned from the database in my projection interface, I thought of a custom annotation for that, but I didn't come up with a construction idea.

Can anyone share a solution to this scenario.

**Ex My Enum**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum PersonType {

    PHYSICAL_PERSON("F","Physical Person"),
    LEGAL_PERSON("J","Legal Person");
    
    private String code;
    private String description;

}
```

**My inteface projection**

```
public interface PersonProjection {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getObs();
    String getPersonType();
}
```

**My repository**

```
@Query(value = "select p.id as id, p.description as name, p.obs as obs, p.type as personType from public.person p where p.code = :code", nativeQuery = true)
List<PersonProjection> findByCode(@Param("code") Long code);
```

My interface is being returned from the database like this:

```
id=1,name="Mike",obs="Tests",personType="F";
```

Is there any way in this projection interface I can use an annotation where I can get the description of the enum by the value of the returned string

**Ex:**

```
public interface PersonProjection {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getObs();
    @DescriptionEnum(PersonType.class)
    String getPersonType();
}
```

In the domain class with the JPA annotations I can, but since I'm out, returning the data in an interface like a DTO, I can't get the same resource.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417190/spring-data-jpa-custom-type-conversion-in-interface-based-projection