# Add custom converter to ProxyProjectionFactory for Interface-based Projections

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

After updating to Spring Boot 3.2 and therefore also Hibernate 6.2 the database column types for enum values changed from integer to smallint [more information here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#:%7E:text=SqlTypes.JSON%20yet.-,Datatype,-for%20enums).

Because of that we changed the db columns to smallint.
Smallint on the other hand gets mapped to short by hibernate.

With that we are having problems with interface-based projections containing enums:

```
public interface MyProjection { 
  MyEnum getEnum();
}
```

Because there is no default converter we get this error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot project java.lang.Short to com.bbraun.nemo.enums.MyEnum; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found

at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.potentiallyConvertResult(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:243)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:249)
```

To fix this i tried to add a custom converter Short-To-Enum:

```
@Component
final class ShortToEnumConverterFactory implements ConverterFactory<Short, Enum> {

  @Override
  public <T extends Enum> Converter<Short, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
    return new ShortToEnum(targetType);
  }

  private static class ShortToEnum<T extends Enum> implements Converter<Short, T> {

    private final Class<T> enumType;

    public ShortToEnum(Class<T> enumType) {
      this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(Short source) {
      return this.enumType.getEnumConstants()[source];
    }
  }
```

Registering it via

```
@Configuration
...

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverterFactory(new ShortToEnumConverterFactory());   
  }

...
```

as well as adding it to DefaultConversionService like this

```
DefaultConversionService sharedInstance = (DefaultConversionService)DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance();
    sharedInstance.addConverterFactory(new ShortToEnumConverterFactory());
```

is not fixing it.

The problem is, that in ProxyProjectionFactory a new instance of DefaultConversionService is created, instead of using the sharedInstance:

```
class ProxyProjectionFactory implements ProjectionFactory, BeanClassLoaderAware {

    static final GenericConversionService CONVERSION_SERVICE = new DefaultConversionService();
...
```

This instance is not containing mit added custom converter.

For some time the sharedInstance was used, but - for whatever reason -  it was changed with this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/bd3992dfc56cc53e3be4a6d7ea106594fd7d81e5).

So my question is, is it possible in any way to add a custom converter that is used by ProxyProjectionFactory?

Or should this anyway be handled in a complete different way?

Comment: By any chance did this worked for you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253539/16769477

Answer (score 0):

Complex object conversion was never subject to the conversion service used for projections. The conversion service can adjust for slight conversions (long to int) but in no case for String to complex object conversion.

The underlying entity is what dictates the type that needs to be used in your projection. Alternatively, use `SpEL` through `@Value` as explained in this answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253539/16769477

Comment: I fixed it by using SpEL to invoke a converter. Not pretty but it works. But i still think this is a flaw in Spring Data. I don't think it is a complex conversion. We are talking about an mapping from short to enum, which is the default value in Hibernate 6.2 for enums.